# MYSQL: Upgrade is not supported after a crash or shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 2

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a mysql server running in a docker container. I tried to upgrade the database from version 8.0.29 to version 8.0.30. However, when starting, the following error occurred:

```
2022-09-06T13:13:39.928986Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-09-06T13:13:40.701091Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-09-06T13:13:40.954725Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade is not supported after a crash or shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 2. This redo log was created with MySQL 8.0.29, and it appears logically non empty. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
2022-09-06T13:13:40.954752Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2022-09-06T13:13:41.328075Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-09-06T13:13:41.328265Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-09-06T13:13:41.328299Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

Then I tried to start again in version 8.0.29, but that no longer works either - error message is:

```
2022-09-06T13:31:18.544142Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29) starting as process 1
2022-09-06T13:31:18.682671Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-09-06T13:31:24.588234Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013171] [InnoDB] Cannot boot server version 80029 on data directory built by version 80030. Downgrade is not supported
mysqld: Can't open file: 'mysql.ibd' (errno: 0 - )
2022-09-06T13:31:25.243497Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2022-09-06T13:31:25.243720Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-09-06T13:31:25.243968Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

Any ideas how I can solve the problem?

Comment: Dont use docker for database servers. Install mysql on host

Comment: bugs.mysql.com ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First take a backup of your mysql data directory. Then delete the files ib_logfile*. When you start mysql, it will create new, empty log files.

Also, running with `innodb_fast_shutdown = 2` is a bad idea. Change it to 1. You will still be able to shut down quickly, but mysql will do the minimum possible to get your files in to a consistent, upgradeable state. As you have found, this is important when running Docker where your software versions can be independent of your data.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I moved the ib_logfiles and got `Neither found #innodb_redo subdirectory, nor ib_logfile* files in ./`

Comment: @totalhack Just create the #innodb_redo folder. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427384/cant-start-mysql-after-upgrade